# UIView moving inside its Superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

The problem is inside of moving a subview inside of its superview. Basically, I thought it would move only inside of its superview and once any part was over is would't be visible. But seems I'm wrong since the subview moves over the whole visible area.

What I do is simply change frame's origin of the subview. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `clipsToBounds` property of the parent view to YES/true